# Send all Exceptions to Server in C#

Tags: c#, exception, network-programming

I thought about sending all exceptions created in the programm to a server, but didn't find a good solution. My idea was to create a base class, which, with in the constructor, adds the exception to a queue. A sender does wait on the queue and sends all registered exceptions to the server.
But at the time the exceptions is registered the constructor is not done, which means it is possibile not all values are set when it is send to the server. Is waiting a set amount of ms a good solution or is there a better way to collect all exceptions, that does not require me to do it for every exception/catch manually?
What type of connection should be used? Setting up a tpc connection is expensiv, should I implement a simple UDP based protocol, or is that overkill?

Comment: This is very vague. I am not sure if your server is in c# and your front end is in c#, or only your server ? The answer changes depending on what you are using on the front end. For example, if you are using blazor, you could use an exception filter to catch all exceptions, if you are using Angular, you could use a global interceptor. Please add more context

Comment: By the way I have done this in a few projects, if you do add more detail, I'm sure I can help :)

Comment: Both frontend and server is in C#. I found [FirstChanceException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-receive-first-chance-exception-notifications) today, this sounds like what I am looking for. Is it any good?

Comment: yeah That looks good!  c# is still a little vauge. Are you using .netcore with DI ? If so there is a much easier and more common way. If you are using .netcore I will post the solution.

Comment: Yes I use  .netcore and DI.

Comment: I did post a answer. Let me know if you need any more help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at a article by Jason Taylor on how to do this. Here is his github source code link.

https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/WebUI/Filters/ApiExceptionFilterAttribute.cs

I also wrote a simplified example for you. Hope this helps.

Exception filter:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace Multitrust.API.Filters
{
public class ApiExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public ApiExceptionFilter() 
    {
    }


public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{

    HandleException(context);
}

private void HandleException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    //This will catch all exceptions, you can them log them here. I recommend using serilog. 
}

}
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        options.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilter()));
        
  //Bind other services...

 }
```

Let me know if you need any help with this.

Happy coding!

Comment: Not only a good solution, but an interesting feature I didn't know about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use existing ones rather than write custom error catchers. Using a nlog style solution makes the project more universal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It seems like with nlog I have to explicitly log everything manually. I want to automatically log all exceptions which are generated.